# Invariant names for different ADO.NET providers

Tags: nhibernate, ado.net, database-connection

For a proposed change in NHibernate drivers to make it easier to build and deploy NHibernate-based solutions (see [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/nhibernate-development/browse_thread/thread/2a7d45c747db4970)) we need to collect the invariant provider names of the following RDBMS:

- Adaptive Server Anywhere
- DB2
- Firebird
- Ingres
- MySQL
- Oracle
- SQLite
- SQL CE
- Sybase

You don't need to know all of them to answer this question; just enter the ones you know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks like it was faster on our list :-)

Here are the names, thanks to Frans Bouma and Jason Dentler

- Adaptive Server Anywhere: "iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere"
- DB2: "IBM.Data.DB2"
- Firebird: "FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient"
- Ingres: "Ingres.Client"
- MySQL: "MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
- Oracle: ODP.NET: "Oracle.DataAccess.Client"
- Oracle: MS Oracle: "System.Data.OracleClient"
- SQLite: System.Data.SQLite"
- SQL CE: v3.0: "System.Data.SqlServerCe"
- SQL CE: v3.5: "System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5"
- Sybase ASE: "Sybase.Data.AseClient"